# Clicking on submenu, in a sidebar, go to a url with Material Design using Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, material-design-lite

I am working on a book collection program and I have a static `sidebar` which will have options and when you click on some of the options it sends you to a url.

I can't get the *going to url* part to work.

So I just have a sidenav, then a menu item called `Store` and then a submenu with an item called `Amazon`.

There may be typos, as I typed this as the code is on a different computer. Basically, how do I get where a submenu will send me to a url?  I can do it from the menu item.

```
<md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true" class="app-sidenav">
  <md-nav-list>
    <button md-list-item>Book Choices</button>
    <button md-button>
      <span md-list-item
         [mdMenuTriggerFor]="amazon">Stores</span></button>
  </md-nav-list>
</md-sidenav>

<md-menu #amazon>
  <button md-button>
    <span md-menu-item>
     <span (click)="'http://amazon.com'">Amazon</span>
    </span>
  </button>
</md-menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this thing `(click)="'http://amazon.com'"` does nothing at all since you just passed a string.

have you tried `(click)="window.open('http://amazon.com', '_blank')"`?

or create a function that does the `window.open(parameter)`

```
openlink(url: string)
{
  window.open(string, "_blank");
}

// HTML attribute
(click)="openlink('http://amazon.com')"
```

Comment: Let me try that and see.  I put in the single quotes as it complained about the colon. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these work. The click is getting ignored, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Try to move the (click) atritube to its parent `md-nav-item` if not then `md-button`. I think it would work if you put the (click) attribute on `md-button`.

Comment: Moving it is all that was needed.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot navigate to a url using this expression `(click)="'http://amazon.com'"`. You need to use `window.location.href` or `window.open` method. Here is how you can do that:

```
<md-menu #amazon>
  <button md-button>
    <span md-menu-item>
     <span (click)="gotoUrl('http://www.amazon.com')">Amazon</span>
    </span>
  </button>
</md-menu>
```

in your typescript code, define the `gotoUrl()` method:

```
gotoUrl(url:string){
    window.location.href=url;
}
```

if you want to open the url in a new tab in the browser, then use this code:

```
gotoUrl(url:string){
    window.open(url, "_blank");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So while you can use (click) events in angular, if all you need to do is navigate to another url you can always just use good old html and an anchor link. If that's all your looking for keep it simple

```
<md-menu #amazon>
  <button md-button>
    <a md-menu-item href="http://amazon.com">
     Amazon
    </a>
  </button>
</md-menu>
```

If you still want to use a click you can, and the answer below was correct it just had a typo

So add a method in your component like:

```
goToUrl(url: string) {
    window.open(url);
}
```

And then in your view

```
<md-menu #amazon>
    <button md-button>
        <span md-menu-item (click)="goToUrl('http://amazon.com')">
        Amazon
        </span>
     </button>
</md-menu>
```